# passing docker flag --net=host to selenium/standalone-chrome-debug, image fails

Tags: selenium, docker

trying to add --net=host to Selenium standalone image so it would work with localhost, but the image fails:

```
➜  ~ docker run --net=host -ti selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
sudo: unable to send audit message: Operation not permitted
Waiting xvfb...
sudo: unable to send audit message: Operation not permitted
/opt/bin/entry_point.sh: line 32:    17 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) sudo -E -i -u seluser $(for E in $(grep -vxFf asseluser asroot); do echo $E=$(eval echo \$$E); done) DISPLAY=$DISPLAY xvfb-run -n $SERVERNUM --server-args="-screen 0 $GEOMETRY -ac +extension RANDR" java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar ${SE_OPTS}
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
➜  ~
```

without --net=host:

```
➜  ~ docker run -ti selenium/standalone-chrome-debug 
Waiting xvfb...
12:52:22.181 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60'
12:52:22.183 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
23/10/2016 12:52:22 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbport
23/10/2016 12:52:22 passing arg to libvncserver: 5900
```

EDIT

Docker version 1.12.2

The docker image is up for a few seconds, then crash

```
➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
27e750f48d1c        selenium/standalone-chrome-debug   "/opt/bin/entry_point"   5 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds                            romantic_hopper
➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

The official docker-selenium images are not being tested with `--net=host` AFAIK

You can alternatively use [elgalu/docker-selenium](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium)

```
docker run --rm -ti --name=grid --net=host \
  --privileged=true --shm-size=1g \
  -e PICK_ALL_RANDMON_PORTS=true \
  -e SELENIUM_HUB_PORT=4444 \
  elgalu/selenium
```

Comment: I've tried, without the --net=host flag the docker run, with it I get the following  ➜  ~ docker run -ti --net=host  elgalu/selenium
sudo: unable to send audit message: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/entry.sh: line 12:     7 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) sudo rm -f /var/lib/dbus/machine-id

Comment: Where are you running this? Core OS? OSX? Google Cloud? Ubuntu laptop?

Comment: I am running this on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: can you run the exact command I pasted (it looks like you only took a part of it)

Comment: Do you have latest docker 1.12.2 ?

Comment: Nope. Updating, checking and I will be back with an update

Comment: If that doesn't help you can try passing `--privileged=true` as explained here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5899#issuecomment-213528049 though is strange that works for me in Ubuntu 16:04 I wonder what OS config might be causing this, perhaps some security customization or some custom docker config?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126620/discussion-between-captain-meow-meow-and-leo-gallucci).